# Unable to upload image on Webdav Server. iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, file-upload, webdav

I have just downloaded the WTClient from [here](http://code.google.com/p/wtclient/). It is used for connecting WebDav Servers through iOS.

What I am doing here is to upload a .png file. So, I downloaded its sample app and updated it with mine credentials but all in vain. I am facing lots of difficulties in acheiving this. And I don't know what would be going wrong?

Code is as follows :

**Upload Btn Action**

```
- (IBAction)uploadFile:(id)sender 
{
    transferType = TransferTypeUpload;
    [self prepareTransferClient];
}
```

**Prepare Client**

```
- (void)prepareTransferClient {

self.transferClient = [[[WTClient alloc] initWithLocalURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"png"]]
                            remoteURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/test"]
                             username:@"user"
                             password:@"pass"] autorelease];

[self.transferClient setDelegate:self];
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startTransfer) withObject:nil];
}
```

StartTransfer is the WTClient's function which is in-built to start Uploading data. Please help!

P.S I tried checking the server for correction via the App [WebDav Navigator](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/webdav-navigator/id382551345?mt=8) and I could upload images.

Basically, All I want is to upload images on WebDav Server and I am very new to this, so I have found just this framework. Are you aware of any other alternatives through which I could interact with WebDav Server?

Any kind of suggestions, answers are welcomed.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: why don't you use ASIHttpRequest ..I always use it for uploading audio/photos ... its so easy  [fromhere](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

Comment: Would it work on uploading to WebDav Servers then?

Comment: Hey, I have accomplished the same task. Upload/Download files using webDav Server. I have included related classes into my project. I have downloaded it from GitHub from `Jason Kichline`.

Comment: @mayuur its httprequest it should work ,even i did not try it on a webdav !!

Comment: @M.Othman I think uploading using `Http` and `Webdav` is completely different. So, for `webdav`, we have to included third party classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I got the way......

Download [this from GitHub](https://github.com/jkichline/ACConnect/tree/master/src/ACWebDAV)

And in this, `Classes` and `Request` contain the all the classes for uploading, downloading, moving, copying, deleting files.

This is the perfect solution of your problem. I have been successful using this `ACWebDavClasses` for uploading, downloading, copying, moving files on webdav server....

Let me know if this would help you......:)

Comment: For Uploading file, you can start with...

ACWebDAVClient *propReq = [[ACWebDAVClient alloc]init];
    [propReq initWithHost:@"your webdav url" username:self.username password:self.password];

[client1 uploadFile:filename toPath:localDirPath fromPath:remotePath];

Comment: One question here, toPath should be remotePath and fromPath localDirpath right???

Comment: It worked!!! Amazing.. Thank you so much! I was unable to find anything regarding this.

Comment: Its my pleasure that I could have helped you..:)

Comment: mayuur can you help me with some directions too ? What to input on the "Remote URL" text field and the local filename ? where is it stored ? in the app's documents ?